# SVN showing Windows Firewall icon instead of Green Tick

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, visualsvn-server

Suddenly a fully up to date repo looks like this:

[image: a]

A separate repo looks like this (folder names redacted) - as you can see, out of date files still have the correct icon (red !):

[image: b]

Inside a folder, any up to date files look the same:

[image: c]

I've tried *SVN Cleanup -> Refresh shell overlays*, but this had no effect:

[image: d]

What is causing this and how can I get my lovely green check mark back?

[image: e]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try letting Windows rebuild the icon cache.

1. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Esc</kbd> to open the Task Manager.
2. Kill `explorer.exe`<sup>1</sup> (your taskbar will disappear).
3. Click menu *File* → *New task*
4. Type `cmd` <kbd>Enter</kbd> to open the command prompt.
5. Type (or copy-and-paste):

   ```
   del "%localappdata%\IconCache.db" /A
   ```

   <kbd>Enter</kbd>
6. Go to the Task Manager and click menu *File* → *New task*.
7. Type `explorer.exe` <kbd>Enter</kbd> to regain your task bar.
8. Restart your PC to let it rebuild your icon cache<sup>2</sup>.

<sup>1</sup>) Explorer might hold the icon cache file hostage in which case you can't delete it. That's why the `explorer.exe` process must be killed.

<sup>2</sup>) A reboot is not required for everyone.

Comment: This worked perfectly (no reboot needed) - thanks a lot! One random thing I observed: I accidentally started `explorer` instead of `cmd` at *Step 4*... this is what happened: http://i.imgur.com/Qc2xB8M.png EEK, it's the 7-Zip fairy!!